# 'self' captured by a closure error with &&, || operator

Tags: swift, initialization, operators

I have a initialize method. 
Why do I see **'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized** if I use && or || operand.

```
var type:Type? = .non

init(dictionary:[String:AnyObject]){

  if let type  = dictionary["type"] as? Int {
        self.type = Type.init(rawValue: type)!
  }


  //'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

  if self.type == .picture || self.type == .textWithPicture {
    //........
  }     
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole class declaration? Just omit the methods.

Comment: because you may not pass in the if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you inheriting your class from NSObject? If yes, you need to call super's init method before using this class's properties.

Comment: Yes mate, got it. I did not aware of it.Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630031/calling-super-init-in-initializer-of-nsobject-subclass-in-swift